# No solution to a warning when executing a stored procedure? "Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation"

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, insert, execute, declare

I get the warning "Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation." and I cannot find the source of the problem. The code is below, what I basically want to do is to insert values in a table, based on the execution of 33 stored procedures (the coding for the execution is the same, so I give just a few examples below). I have looked for errors in the invoked SP, but found none since they all return the expected results based on test files.

Any suggestions for a solution?

CODE:

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SKL_SaveAdminKontroll_result]

    AS
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

    declare @SQL VarChar(max)
    set @SQL = '

    DELETE FROM [dbo].[SKL_AdminKontroll_result]

    DECLARE @kommuner VARCHAR(300)
    DECLARE @landsting VARCHAR(300)
    DECLARE @tableName VARCHAR(100) 

    SET @kommuner=''select id from [StatistikinlamningAdminSKL].[dbo].[Enhet] WHERE [EnhetsTyp] = 1''
    SET @landsting=''select id from [StatistikinlamningAdminSKL].[dbo].[Enhet] WHERE [EnhetsTyp] = 2''
    SET @tableName=''GR_PS09_1''

        INSERT INTO [dbo].[SKL_AdminKontroll_result] ([Värde],[Typ],Enhetsid,Adminkontroll,[Datum för hämtat värde]) 
            EXEC dbo.SKL_admin_KN_aform @tableName, @kommuner
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[SKL_AdminKontroll_result] ([Värde],[Typ],Enhetsid,Adminkontroll,[Datum för hämtat värde]) 
            EXEC dbo.SKL_admin_KN_annan_AID @tableName, @kommuner
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[SKL_AdminKontroll_result] ([Värde],[Typ],Enhetsid,Adminkontroll,[Datum för hämtat värde]) 
            EXEC dbo.SKL_admin_KN_ansvar @tableName, @kommuner
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[SKL_AdminKontroll_result] ([Värde],[Typ],Enhetsid,Adminkontroll,[Datum för hämtat värde])    
            EXEC dbo.SKL_admin_LT_aform @tableName, @landsting
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[SKL_AdminKontroll_result] ([Värde],[Typ],Enhetsid,Adminkontroll,[Datum för hämtat värde])    
            EXEC dbo.SKL_admin_LT_annan_AID @tableName, @landsting
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[SKL_AdminKontroll_result] ([Värde],[Typ],Enhetsid,Adminkontroll,[Datum för hämtat värde])    
            EXEC dbo.SKL_admin_LT_ansvar @tableName, @landsting
    '

        EXEC (@SQL)
    END
```

Best regards,

Hannes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a warning, one of your stored procs is performing aggregation, and it's letting you know that `NULL` values aren't captured in aggregates.

You'll have to investigate your stored procs to find out where the aggregation is taking place, but if you're getting the results you expect then there is no problem.

You can suppress the warning if you want:

```
SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF 
GO
```

Probably a bad practice to be suppressing warnings.